# Remove Array Item from ListPreference

Tags: android, accelerometer, listpreference

I have a List Preference for Accelerometer mode in my preference activity which I'm loading purely from xml. If a users device does not have or support an Accelerometer I wont to completely remove the item in the array. Do I have to create a separate list preference for this one option to remove it? (I would prefer to keep them all in one.) How can it be removed with the below setup?

Thanks for the tip.

Jason

```
<string-array name="mode_text">
        <item>Others Modes</item>
        <item>Others Modes</item>
        <item>Accelerometer Mode</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="mode_values">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When  you say you want to "completely remove the item in the array", do you mean you want the ListPreference to not show in the PreferenceScreen? Or you want it to return a null value when you try to get the set value?

Okay, I understand now. I think you can't remove just that item in the array. You have to set new arrays for the entries and entryValues for your ListPreference, programatically.
You find the ListPreference by its key.

Here is an example:

```
    if (accelerometerNotSupported) {
        ListPreference accelMode = (ListPreference) findPreference("acceleratorMode");
        accelMode.setEntries(new String[]{"Others Modes","Others Modes"});
        accelMode.setEntryValues(new String[]{"0", "1"});
    }
```

That will change your list preference to have only those two options.

Comment: No the individual list preference entry Accelerometer Mode. Not the whole preference, as other modes will be applicable for selection so the others still need to be shown "Other Mode" etc.

Comment: Yes, I saw it just now. I got it, let me think how you could solve that.

Comment: Finally found the answer after hours of trying other things. It is kind of amazing how hard it is to google for this problem considering how common it would seem at first glance